# Finding average speed knowing acceleration

Tags: calculus, self-learning, kinematics

Particle, initially at rest travels in a straight line and its acceleration satisfies $$a=0.1(t-5)^2 $$for $0\leq t\leq5$

Find its average speed. during the first$5$ seconds.

I don't expect answers as this clearly is a homework, just a hint what formulas to use to find the answer. Initially I thought that it is $$\frac{\text{final velocity-initial velocity}}{2}$$
but my answer and books answer is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

We need to consider an integral average for the speed $|v(t)|$ with $a(t)=\frac{dv(t)}{dt}$ for $t\in[0,5]$, that is

$$\frac{\int_0^5 |v(t)| dt}{5}$$

Comment: but isnt $v=\frac{ds}{dt}$?

Comment: ops...sorry I fix of course!

Comment: and that is exactly what I did! I got 4.16666..../5 and the answer in the book is 3.125

Comment: @KuderaSebastian did you considered the absolute value?

Comment: no I didn't, do you think I should draw the velocity time graph and split the integrals?

Comment: @KuderaSebastian yes speed is different from velocity, you need to consider the absolute value that is split the integrals and change sign for the negative part.

Comment: @KuderaSebastian Yes I've checked in this way you should obtain 3.125!

Comment: thank you very very much !

Comment: @KuderaSebastian By the way, it seems that $v(t)$ should be always positive, maybe you make a little mistake with the integration, check and let me know if you need some other indication! Bye

Comment: Ignore me completely :D I integrated acceleration and thought it is velocity that I am integrating. I just wasted your time sorry for this and thanks for the help.

Comment: @KuderaSebastian Don't worry, you are welcome! Sometimes talking with someone else it sufficient to clarify. Bye

Comment: Yeas, exactly. For some reason, I only integrated the acceleration once and thought the job is done. while of course integrating acceleration gives velocity and then it is integrating velocity which spits out the distance.

Comment: @KuderaSebastian remember also that you need to check that v(t) is non negative since we need the average speed!in this case $v(t)\ge0$ thus it is ok. Another detail also the initial velocity should be declared by the problem since it can be any value and not necessarly $v(0)=0$.

Comment: Of course, they did say that the particle starts from the rest, and of course the formula for the acceleration tells you that the velocity is positive in the 5 seconds.

Comment: @KuderaSebastian Good point! You are completely right!

Answer (score 2):

Your formula is only valid if the acceleration is constant, which it is not in your case. Hint:
The average value of a function on $[a,b]$ is
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)\,dx
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

The average speed is the total distance travelled divided by the time.

Integrating once we get an expression for the velocity, namely $$v=\frac{0.1}{3}\left[(t-5)^3+125\right]$$

Integrating again gives displacement, or in this case, distance travelled, since the motion is not reversed in the first $5$ seconds:

$$s=\frac{0.1}{3}\left[\frac 14(t-5)^4+125t\right]_0^5$$

Evaluating this and dividing by $5$ gives the answer $3.125$

Answer (score 0):

Velocity is different from speed. For average speed, you'll need to use the equation of $\frac{d}{\Delta t}$. Where d is the sum of all the absolute displacements (also the total distance travelled). So, the hint here is likely you'll need to consider cases since positive and negative displacement shouldn't cancel out each other as they both contribute to the distance.